# Is it possible/advisable to file a patent while traveling to a foreign country?

Tags: foreign

Suppose I had an idea for an invention in the U.S. but then travelled abroad before finishing writing the patent text itself and filed it with the USPTO from abroad. Is this an advisable scenario?

Comment: I don’t believe it matters at all where you conceive of the invention or where you are located. However I prefer an answer from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: I know relatively little about the international filing process but what I would like to avoid is to have a scenario where I have to obtain a foreign filing license from the abroad country - considering that I have a solid option not to travel if it complicates things too much.

Comment: It seems to depend per country and sometimes per citizenships/residencies the inventor has. From what I can tell, for my specific situation no foreign filing license is required, even if some of the inventive activity occurs abroad (the foreign country is Greece, but I am not a national there).

Comment: As long as your permanent address is in the US, I'd assume you would be filing as a US resident regardless where the computer is when the filing is done. That said, I'm not a lawyer so I'm not posting this as an answer.